# Use a Object sent from Asp Controller in Vue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

For my application I use Vue and ASP. I am trying to do the following:

1. At runtime I send a post request via axios from my Vue file, so I will access the following part in my **controller** (In this part I set some values for the member lastname and firstname from my ViewModelName and return the viewmodel. I use JsonResult instead of IActionResult to prevent the necessity of a page reload):

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Human/Name")]
        public JsonResult Name([FromBody]ViewModelName vm) 
        {         
            vm.lastname = "testLastName";
            vm.firstname= "testFirstName"
            return Json(vm);
        }
```

2. In my **view** I am trying to send this object to my Vue-File like in the following:

```
@using BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels
@model BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName

<div id="app" data="@Model"></div>

 @section scripts { <script src="~/dist/something/bundle.js"></script> }
```

3. In the last step I want to access my viewmodel values in my **Vue-File** with the following method:

```
showModel: function () {
                this.someData =document.getElementById('app')?.attributes['data'].value.firstname;
                console.log(this.someData)         
            },
```

My problem is that the values from the viewmodel are not accessable from my Vue-File.
Hopefully I could explain my question understandable. I am thankful for any help!

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the answers I tried the following:

`console.log(document.getElementById('app')?.attributes)`

This gives me the following output:

```
NamedNodeMap {0: id, 1: data, 2: data-v-app, id: id, data: data, data-v-app: data-v-app, length: 3}


id
baseURI: "https://localhost:6001/Human/Name"
childNodes: NodeList []
firstChild: null
isConnected: false
lastChild: null
localName: "id"
name: "id"
namespaceURI: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "id"
nodeType: 2
nodeValue: "app"
ownerDocument: document
ownerElement: div#app
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
prefix: null
previousSibling: null
specified: true
textContent: "app"
value: "app"
__proto__: Attr



data
baseURI: "https://localhost:6001/Human/Name"
childNodes: NodeList(0)
length: 0
__proto__: NodeList
firstChild: null
isConnected: false
lastChild: null
localName: "data"
name: "data"
namespaceURI: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "data"
nodeType: 2
nodeValue: "BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"
ownerDocument: document
ownerElement: div#app
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
prefix: null
previousSibling: null
specified: true
textContent: "BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"
value: "BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"
__proto__: Attr





data-v-app
baseURI: "https://localhost:6001/Human/Name"
childNodes: NodeList(0)
length: 0
__proto__: NodeList
firstChild: null
isConnected: false
lastChild: null
localName: "data-v-app"
name: "data-v-app"
namespaceURI: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "data-v-app"
nodeType: 2
nodeValue: ""
ownerDocument: document
ownerElement: div#app
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
prefix: null
previousSibling: null
specified: true
textContent: ""
value: ""
__proto__: Attr
length: 3
data: data
baseURI: "https://localhost:6001/Human/Name"
childNodes: NodeList []
firstChild: null
isConnected: false
lastChild: null
localName: "data"
name: "data"
namespaceURI: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "data"
nodeType: 2
nodeValue: "BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"
ownerDocument: document
ownerElement: div#app
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
prefix: null
previousSibling: null
specified: true
textContent: "BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"
value: "BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"
__proto__: Attr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with a serialization of the resulting object in the view

Answer (score 0):

`attributes['data'].value` will allways be string, so you cannot read .firstname directly.

Try running `console.log(document.getElementById('app')?.attributes)` in this place of code and show us what did you get.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question with your requested information. Hopefully this is helpful

Comment: So value of attriute data is:
`"BC.Client.WebApp.Mde.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelName"`
which is name of class. 

You have 2 options: 
1.pass your data as string containing JSON
2.Pass lastname  ans firstname in 2 sepparate html attributes.